# dtypes returning AttributeError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm using pandas for the first time. I have read data from an Excel file into a data frame, but can't seem to do anything with it.

The dataframe is called ParsedData. It exists and contains data:

```
>>> ParsedData  
>>>       USD#     County Name   USD Name    Density   Area
>>> 0    D0101       Neosho        Erie      0.847692  325.0
>>> ...
```

I can confirm that it is a dataframe:

```
>>> type(ParsedData)
>>> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

However, attempting to determine the dtypes of my columns fails:

```
>>> ParsedData.dtypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 1, in <module>
    ParsedData.dtypes
  File "C:\Python34\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 611, in displayhook
    text = repr(value)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 72, in __repr__
    return str(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 51, in __str__
    return self.__unicode__()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 982, in __unicode__
    width, height = get_terminal_size()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\terminal.py", line 33, in get_terminal_size
    return shutil.get_terminal_size()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 1071, in get_terminal_size
    size = os.get_terminal_size(sys.__stdout__.fileno())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

What's going on here?

Comment: You seem to be using IDLE. Try not using IDLE.

Comment: @user2357112 - why?